# Can not type at login screen

Tags: windows-10, login

This morning I am having an issue where I cannot type anything at the login screen. I have tried to boot in Safe Mode, and can get there, just not able to type on that as well. I have tried to use the Ease of Access options, but it will not open the menu.

Comment: Do you have PC? Laptop? What make/model? Do you have a USB keyboard you can try?

Comment: It is an MS I GE72 laptop and I do not have a USB keyboard.

Comment: Is it still under warranty? There are lots of complaints about MSI keyboards - here is one "MSI should have stuck to making good motherboards because we're currently the guinea pigs for their attempts at making laptops.  This one has a huge design flaw in that the motherboard has a sharp object that cuts in the wiring and overtime will render the keyboard useless(and who knows what else).  I found out the hard way when some of the keys on my keyboard just stopped working."

Comment: Yes I have had it less then 2 weeks.

Comment: Replace it under warranty.

Comment: @DAvidPostill Drat, I guess the same thing happened in my previous Asus.