# Can't enter password on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I downloaded windows 10 from windows 8.1 on my lenovo netbook. All I am getting is a blue screen and when I click on the password box nothing happens so I can't put password in. Thanks

Comment: Related/Same question: http://superuser.com/questions/964926/can-not-type-at-login-screen

Comment: What sort of blue screen?

Comment: You downloaded windows 10 (so your disk is now a bit fuller) but you did not yet try to install it? Or did you try to installl it and did that go wrong? And on the blue screen (only blue, nothing else, no password boxes, just blueness) ...  Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/982550/edit0 your post and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with my Lenovo Yoga 7. I called support: Disconnect AC adapter and then press power button (physical power button, as power button on the screen would not respond). Apparently this is a Windows 10 glitch.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior a lot on my Windows 10 tablet and desktop, wherein I can move the mouse around, but the password box doesn't take any key input. What I end up doing is hitting escape a few times or WINDOWS-L. Both of those will bring the lock screen background back, and after that, I can login normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> it restarted where I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> several times (for HP Pavilion G6 series), then from the startup menu I choose System Recovery by hitting <kbd>F11</kbd>, and the problem is solved in a simple way.

Comment: You could have written that much shorter. E.g. I had the same problem and used system recovery to reinstall windows.

Answer (score 0):

Select ease of access at the bottom right, and choose on screen keyboard. Enter your password by clicking the keys on the on screen keyboard. Windows comes up and your real keyboard works.

Comment: If there's nothing but a blue screen, where is the ease of access selection?

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing just happened to me.

Nothing available on the screen apart from Ease of access Network and Shutdown/Power options.

How I fixed it was:

- Shutdown -> Sleep
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock.
- Click the screen

This brought back the proper login UI. You could try using the <kbd>Sleep</kbd> button if your laptop has one

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can type your password, even though password bar is disabled. Just click on that bar, type password and hit enter (like you normally do)